# Cannot call a js function from external loaded file on wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, scope

I am having troubles calling a function from a external loaded file.

I have **search_form.php**, from where i call the function, the **client.js** file where the functions are defined, and the **plugin_functions.php** file where i load the client.js file.

In plugin_functions.php file i have the following code:

```
console.log('loaded_client'); 
function load_client_scripts() {
     wp_register_script('js-client', PLUGIN_URL.'includes/js/client.js',array('jquery'),false);
     wp_enqueue_script( 'js-client' );
 };
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_client_scripts' );
```

In client.js i define the function as follows:

```
(function($) {
    function validateForm(){
        console.log('Form validated');
    };
})( jQuery );
```

Finally, in search_form.php i call the function with onclick:

```
 <div onclick="validateForm()">
    CLICK ME
 </div>
```

Now, the js file is loading properly, because i get the console output 'loaded_client'. However, when i click the div, i get ReferenceError: validateForm() is not defined.

What am i doing wrong? It surely is a scope problem, but i cannot figure it out.

Comment: In console what error are display? and Ctrl + U check your JS are link or not?

Comment: Check the last paragraph, the JS file is linked. The error i get is ReferenceError: validateForm() is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($) {
 window.validateForm = function(){
    console.log('Form validated');
};
})( jQuery );

<div onclick="window.validateForm()">
CLICK ME
</div>
```

You are correct, in your example the scope is wrong because wrapped in `(function($) {` this anonymous function.

Edit for clarity: If you want it to be a globally accessible function you can attach it to the window object like on this example.

Comment: I tried to move validateForm function outside the parent function, but is not working. Also, i added the "window" before the function name, both places.. I get the same error on the console.

Comment: You can copy paste the code from this answer and it will work. You need to set the function as a window scope variable such as I am doing in the above example. If that code does not work, your script is not being included correctly.

Comment: This is why i cannot figure it out, because outside the enviornment, everything should work and it is working. The file is included, because  i get the "loaded_client" output on the console.

Comment: Move the `console.log('loaded_client')` to the last line of `load_client_scripts()` and see if it still outputs, in its current form you don't know that it doesn't error in the next line.

Comment: It worked with your example. As i inspected the client.js file from inspect element, i saw that it was not containing my functions. It was a cache problem. Now, the function is declared on the window space, as in your example. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, good luck. If you are satisfied, if you can accept my answer that would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to loading JS into footer.

Set footer true. I think it will work.

```
wp_register_script( 'js-client', PLUGIN_URL.'includes/js/client.js',array('jquery'),false,true);
```